# Replace кавычки в кавычках " " " " c#

Tags: c#, строки

Как включить кавычки внутрь строки?

Например, строка   `{"result":[]}`

Пробую так:

```
string s = Response.Replace ("{"result":[]}"," ");
```

но не компилируется.

Comment: Для того, чтобы распарсить JSON, пользуйтесь парсером JSON, а не регулярками.

Comment: он у меня невалидный, с сервера приходит два json, один такой, один нормальный, нужно этот удалить

Comment: Тогда бейте по голове тапком программистов сервера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы указать кавычку внутри строкового литерала, используйте `\`:

```
"{\"result\":[]}"
```

Если вы используете `@`-литералы, то кавычку нужно удвоить:

```
@"{""result"":[]}"
```

---

Документация: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/string